# Sorting Firebase Data Based on Child Values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to sort my Firebase query by the timestamps on each post child. Instead, I'm just getting the data as it's stored in the database, unsorted. I'm using the firebase npm package.

The data is structured as followed:

```
posts
   -Lsx-tFbXe83gANXP3TD
       -timestamp: 1466171493193
   -Lsx-sWzXe83gANWNM3R
       -timestamp: 1466171493111
```

Here is my javascript code that I wrote using: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

```
firebase.database()
      .ref("posts")
      .orderByChild("timestamp")
      .on("value", function(snapshot) {
        _this.setState({
          posts: Object.values(snapshot.val()),
          loading: false
      });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot` you get back contains three pieces of information about the child nodes that match your query:

1. The key
2. The value
3. Their relative position to each other

As soon as you call `snapshot.val()` all information about ordering is lost, since a JSON object can only contain keys and values.

To maintain the order, you'll want to convert the information to an array:

```
var values = [];
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
  values.push(child.val());
})
```